# Unable to add json data to Google sheets through HTTP post request using Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-post, google-account

**Objective:**
To append multiple rows at a time into a google sheet by passing the data as JSON via HTTP post request.

**Steps to produce the problem:**

1. Created a sheet named "test log" in google sheets.
2. Wrote Apps Script to receive JSON data containing multiple records from a HTTP post request and append each reacord to a new row in the sheet. [Find code below]
3. Ran cURL to make a HTTP post request to append the JSON data to the sheet. [Find code below]

**Result:**

1. Apps Script raises the following error.

> Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again.

2. An empty row is added to the sheet after the request is finished.

**Things to note:**
The apps script is deployed as a web-app with access to any annonymus user.

**Things I have tried (None of them worked):**

1. Changed the App Script owner from myself to annonymus. To check if the issue was related to google account.
2. Opened an ingognito window in my browser, then opened the google sheet and ran the cURL.
3. In the post request, removed multiple records from the JSON data and replaced it with one record only.
4. Tried solutions posted to similar question like this on stackoverflow and else where.

**Google Apps-Script Code:**

```
// Google Apps Script Code
var sheetName = "test log"; // Replace with your sheet name

function doGet(e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("GET request processed successfully").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

function doPost(e) {
  // Your code for handling POST requests
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Get JSON payload from the request
  var jsonData = e.postData.contents;
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  // Map incoming data to corresponding headers
  var mappedData = {
    "Date": data.date || "",
    "Energy Consumed (kWh)": data.energyConsumed || "",
    "Meter ID": data.slaveID || "",
    "Gateway Poll Result": data.gatewayPollResult || "",
    "1st Register Value": data.reg1val || "",
    "2nd Register Value": data.reg2val || ""
    // Add more mappings as needed
  };

  // Construct the data array with the correct order
  var orderedData = orderData(mappedData, ["Date", "Energy Consumed (kWh)", "Meter ID", "Gateway Poll Result", "1st Register Value", "2nd Register Value"]);

  // Insert data at the second row (index 1)
  sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, orderedData.length).setValues([orderedData]);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data added successfully").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

// Function to order the data array based on specified headers
function orderData(data, headers) {
  var orderedData = [];

  headers.forEach(function (header) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(header)) {
      orderedData.push(data[header]);
    } else {
      orderedData.push(""); // If the header doesn't have corresponding data, insert an empty string
    }
  });

  return orderedData;
}
```

**appsscript.json:**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

**cURL:**

```
curl -X POST
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-d '[{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"0.00","Meter ID":"1","Gateway Poll Result":"0","1st Register Value":"0","2nd Register Value":"0"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"999259.13","Meter ID":"2","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18803","2nd Register Value":"62898"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"4603.56","Meter ID":"3","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"32081","2nd Register Value":"19084"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"4563.96","Meter ID":"4","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18416","2nd Register Value":"19083"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"42749.73","Meter ID":"5","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18214","2nd Register Value":"64956"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"31587.45","Meter ID":"6","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18166","2nd Register Value":"50919"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"39329.72","Meter ID":"7","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"2031","2nd Register Value":"19478"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"131805.58","Meter ID":"8","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"26161","2nd Register Value":"19707"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"116166.34","Meter ID":"9","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"37336","2nd Register Value":"19677"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"136570.23","Meter ID":"10","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"15960","2nd Register Value":"19714"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"41472.99","Meter ID":"11","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"13560","2nd Register Value":"19486"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"82634.91","Meter ID":"12","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"40212","2nd Register Value":"19613"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"85259.05","Meter ID":"13","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"40550","2nd Register Value":"19618"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"147647.23","Meter ID":"14","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"52912","2nd Register Value":"19724"}]'
 https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp2Q/exec
```

**Headers in the Google sheet:**

- Date
- Panel
- Energy
- Consumed (kWh)
- Meter ID
- Gateway Poll Result
- 1st Register Value
- 2nd Register Value
- Dummy Col 1
- Dummy Col 2

Comment: Try a different spreadsheet, copy paste the code into that spreadsheet's script editor.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you seeing the error in Google App Script execution log or in the platform where you run the http post request?

Comment: Your Consumed header seems to be different in different secttions of your question

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my guess for your goal was correct, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Serenity In the google page that is embedded in the platform after the request is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your sample curl command, it seems that the JSON data is an array. But, in your script, `e.postData.contents` is not used as an array.
- And, in the case of your JSON data in the curl command, the keys of each element are `"Date","Energy Consumed (kWh)","Meter ID","Gateway Poll Result","1st Register Value","2nd Register Value"`. But, in your script, the keys `date, energyConsumed, slaveID, gatewayPollResult, reg1val, reg2val` are used. These keys are not included in your JSON data.
- Also, your curl command is required to be modified.

From this situation, unfortunately, I'm not sure which is your actual situation. So, in this answer, I would like to believe the JSON data in your curl command is the actual value. By this, I would like to propose a modified script as follows.

When your following JSON data is used,

```
[{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"0.00","Meter ID":"1","Gateway Poll Result":"0","1st Register Value":"0","2nd Register Value":"0"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"999259.13","Meter ID":"2","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18803","2nd Register Value":"62898"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"4603.56","Meter ID":"3","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"32081","2nd Register Value":"19084"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"4563.96","Meter ID":"4","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18416","2nd Register Value":"19083"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"42749.73","Meter ID":"5","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18214","2nd Register Value":"64956"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"31587.45","Meter ID":"6","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18166","2nd Register Value":"50919"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"39329.72","Meter ID":"7","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"2031","2nd Register Value":"19478"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"131805.58","Meter ID":"8","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"26161","2nd Register Value":"19707"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"116166.34","Meter ID":"9","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"37336","2nd Register Value":"19677"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"136570.23","Meter ID":"10","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"15960","2nd Register Value":"19714"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"41472.99","Meter ID":"11","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"13560","2nd Register Value":"19486"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"82634.91","Meter ID":"12","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"40212","2nd Register Value":"19613"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"85259.05","Meter ID":"13","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"40550","2nd Register Value":"19618"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"147647.23","Meter ID":"14","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"52912","2nd Register Value":"19724"}]
```

your script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("GET request processed successfully").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

function doPost(e) {
  var sheetName = "test log"; // Replace with your sheet name

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var jsonData = e.postData.contents;
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  // --- I modified the below script.
  var headers = ["Date", "Energy Consumed (kWh)", "Meter ID", "Gateway Poll Result", "1st Register Value", "2nd Register Value"];
  var orderedData = [headers, ...data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h] || null))];
  // ---

  sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, orderedData.length, orderedData[0].length).setValues(orderedData);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data added successfully").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

- In this sample, the header is added. But, if you are not required to add the header, please modify `var orderedData = [headers, ...data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h] || null))];` to `var orderedData = data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h] || null));`.

#### IMPORTANT

- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Testing:

The sample curl command is as follows. Please replace your Web Apps URL.

```bash
curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp2Q/exec" \
-d '[{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"0.00","Meter ID":"1","Gateway Poll Result":"0","1st Register Value":"0","2nd Register Value":"0"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"999259.13","Meter ID":"2","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18803","2nd Register Value":"62898"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"4603.56","Meter ID":"3","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"32081","2nd Register Value":"19084"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"4563.96","Meter ID":"4","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18416","2nd Register Value":"19083"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"42749.73","Meter ID":"5","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18214","2nd Register Value":"64956"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"31587.45","Meter ID":"6","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"18166","2nd Register Value":"50919"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"39329.72","Meter ID":"7","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"2031","2nd Register Value":"19478"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"131805.58","Meter ID":"8","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"26161","2nd Register Value":"19707"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"116166.34","Meter ID":"9","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"37336","2nd Register Value":"19677"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"136570.23","Meter ID":"10","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"15960","2nd Register Value":"19714"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"41472.99","Meter ID":"11","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"13560","2nd Register Value":"19486"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"82634.91","Meter ID":"12","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"40212","2nd Register Value":"19613"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"85259.05","Meter ID":"13","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"40550","2nd Register Value":"19618"},{"Date":"1705599163","Energy Consumed (kWh)":"147647.23","Meter ID":"14","Gateway Poll Result":"9","1st Register Value":"52912","2nd Register Value":"19724"}]'
```

When this curl command is run with the above script, the following result is obtained on Spreadsheet.

[image]

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)